# Получить индексы у массива в TypeScript (как keyof у объектов)

Tags: typescript

У меня есть массив, допустим это будет:

```typescript
const testArray = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3",
    "test4"
] as const;
```

Могу ли я получить в тип индексы ключей? Что-то типо `keyof` у объектов:

```typescript
type arrayIndex = keyof typeof testArray; // arrayIndex: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать тип из индексов элементов массива возможно:

```
const testArray = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3",
    "test4"
] as const;
// Создадим конструктор для типов
type IndicesType<T extends readonly string[]> = Exclude<Partial<T>["length"], T["length"]>
// Создаем тип
type ArrayIndex = IndicesType<typeof testArray>;
```

`ArrayIndex` -> **0 | 1 | 2 | 3**

Если надо сделать один раз с жестким указаним типа, можно так

```
type ArrayIndex = Exclude<Partial<typeof testArray>["length"], typeof testArray["length"]>;
```

Если мы создадим тип для переменной, то можно сделать так:

```
type TestType = readonly [string, string, string, string];

const testArray: TestType = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3",
    "test4"
] as const;

type ArrayIndex = Indices<TestType>;
```

Тестируем:

```
function tst(idx: ArrayIndex) {
    console.log(testArray[idx]);
}

tst(3); // Успех
tst(9); // Выдаст ошибку
```

Comment: [Проверить можно здесь](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0CCAnFBDAnjAvDA2gFAwkwBEC0AjGQDTGkWJQBMdDJT0AzO6eZSgAWMoQC6MdBBihIUANyFCUTAAd4MAJJgAJgEtgiADwAVGPAAeCXdJTx0O8ABts0FHrABzfGIB8uGABRC2AnAFcdeCMABXQUKD10J1NffDIneC8oAAsyMVoYEzSMrNy-JRV1GFQMTG1IiwCtXQNjSvgQADM4ZhqsX0VCTrCwYATwOGgACj0dCwAuarQsessAShgAbw4ZcAgQDIA6JxBPKcE+zHxZizE1xQBfCunue+VpgE43pSA)

Comment: Такой вариант подходит только для `readonly`? И могу ли я вместо `string[]` указывать `unkown[]`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson readonly и string[] взято из вашего примера массива. Так что можно их поменять

Comment: Я просто хочу что-то уникальное, которое подойдет для всех типов массивов.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Тогда в первом варианте лучше сделать any[]